# what would be the code for Push Data (from client to server)?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

> Following is the code for data pulling from server and merging it to
>   client side......is there some shortcut code to merge data on server
>   side(without using WCF because i am testing it locally and dont wan to
>   use wcf right now)...plz help or if its stupid question please
>   ignore.. :-)

```
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientDataCache1SyncAgent syncAgent = new ClientDataCache1SyncAgent();
        Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize();

        this.hMSDataSet.Diseases.Merge(this.diseasesTableAdapter.GetData());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the class ClientDataCache1SyncAgent, you should be able to set the SyncDirection for each table in the SyncGroup